# Sometimes winium gives a NoSuchElementException in my code

Tags: robotframework, winium

I have a simple code which gives a No Such Element Exception intermittently.
Sometimes it finds a code,sometimes it is not able to do so. Not sure why winium throws such exception.

Demo Example:

```
def make_call_from_phone(self,extension):

    self.window.find_element_by_id("DialPad").click()  ##Clicks on dialpad
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    time.sleep(10)
    self.window.find_element_by_id("DialPadTextBox").send_keys(extension) 
    ##Enters extension
    time.sleep(10)
    self.window.find_element_by_id("DialPadButton").click() ##Clicks on call 
    button
```

Comment: Without a demo example, it's hard for anyone to give you a solid answer; the best you might get are generic directions and assumptions why it might be happening. Please provide some source that demonstrates the issue - even with sporadic failures.

Comment: Example included above. The last line of code where call button needs to be clicked  fails intermittently with exception No Such Element Found. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: I would check if there is an element with  `DialPadButton` Id.